# How to select unique DB records in SAP

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a table with 3 fields and 10 records. I want to make a SELECT on the 1st field with a WHERE and get the unique values. So if the select return 4 values of the field1 lets say AA, AA, AB, AC, I want to get AA, AB & AC.
How I can do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT field1` or `GROUP BY field1` - Have a look at the standard SQL

Answer (score 4):

Remember you should use OpenSQL when working with abap in SAP. A pretty concise guide can be found here: [Complete OpenSql statements guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/21/a-complete-guide-to-opensql-statements-step-by-step-tutorial-with-screenshots/) written by Tamás Holics. The statement you are looking for I think is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM table INTO TABLE itab
```

This would load all the distinct values from your database table into an internal table for further instructions.